# Has a superhero ever deliberately killed a non-superhero/supervillian?

Tags: marvel, dc

Has one ever killed a 'civilian' deliberately? For the purpose of this question it would be an individual one-on-one situation, not destroying a star to save a galaxy or some such thing. This question is not meant to include supervillains or their semi-super henchmen.

Edit: For the purpose of this question, a superhero would be someone with super-powers, not someone who is 'normal' but has cool gadgets such as Ironman or Batman, etc. Also, I'm referring to the comics not Hollywood movies.

Comment: Punisher kills pretty much everyone he meets.

Comment: Same with Deadpool.

Comment: There's a reason why you don't tug on Superman's cape.

Comment: @MajorStackings That was well placed. +1

Comment: I edited the question to make it more clear what is meant by "superhero".

Comment: Does it have to be Marvel or DC? Thinking of Wonder Wart-Hog.

Comment: @user14111 Either/or. The reason I pose this question to this community is that there is a wealth of knowledge to draw from. I have thousands of comics (mostly silver age) but none contain the answer to my question. Hopefully this question won't be dismissed as irrelevant or not worthy.

Answer (score 9):

Captain American is a soldier, so no surprise there

Example 1:
[image]

Example 2: 
[image]

Comment: Oops, have just deleted Batman's scenes. Thanks, @user14111.
(I still like this, though - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8ULSvR6hhyI)

Comment: I knew Cap. would be on the short list because of WWll. He was created for that very reason.

Comment: @Morgan Wolverine and Wonder Woman are other obvious choices. Superman has his body count as well: http://www.the-fanboy-perspective.com/does-superman-really-kill.html

Answer (score 3):

Batman killed an intellectually handicapped man in Batman No 1 (1941). Does that count?

Source: Cracked.com, [The 6 Most Brutal Murders Committed by Batman](http://www.cracked.com/article_20111_the-6-most-brutal-murders-committed-by-batman.html).

Comment: According to the question, Batman doesn't count.

Comment: @user867 After this answer was posted, the question was edited to disqualify Batman.

Answer (score 1):

Spider-man (played by Tobey Maquire) kills the carjacker who kills his uncle in the first movie, albeit he doesn't make the final blow intentionally - the guy trips over a pipe and falls backwards out the window.